# Convert MIT Scheme code logic into Common Lisp

Tags: scheme, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, mit-scheme

In one of my books i have this scheme code and want to convert it to Common Lisp:

```
(define (make-account balance)

  (define (withdraw amount)
    (if (>= balance amount)
      (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
        balance)
        "Insufficient funds"))

  (define (deposit amount)
    (set! balance (+ balance amount))
      balance)

  (define (dispatch m)
    (cond
      ((eq? m 'withdraw) withdraw)
      ((eq? m 'deposit) deposit)
      (else (error "Unknown request -- MAKE-ACCOUNT" m))))

  dispatch)
```

then i'll create it with :

```
(define acc (make-account 1500))
```

and then call `deposit` or `withdraw` with :

`((acc 'withdraw) 50)` 
or

`((acc 'deposit) 75)`

As far as I understand
`acc` gets replaced with the function `dispatch` and returns either `withdraw` or `deposit`
and then evaluates the expression for example:
`((acc 'withdraw) 50)` -> `((dispatch 'withdraw) 50)` -> `(withdraw 50)`

Now, how do i convert this programm and logic to Common Lisp.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Look up CLOS for starters.

Comment: You can have a look at let-over-lambda book section 5.7 for a dlambda implementation for perhaps a cleaner style: https://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/toc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic structure is the same, but you use `FLET` or `LABELS` to define local functions within a function. In this case you need to use `LABELS` because the functions refer to each other.

In Common Lisp you have to use `FUNCALL` to call functions dynamically. This makes this style of functional programming inconvenient; Common Lisp programmers generally use `DEFSTRUCT` or `CLOS`.

```
(defun make-account (balance)
  (labels
   ((withdraw (amount)
      (if (>= balance amount)
          (decf balance amount)
        (error "Insufficient funds")))
    (deposit (amount)
      (incf balance amount))
    (dispatch (m)
      (cond
       ((eq m 'withdraw) #'withdraw)
       ((eq m 'deposit) #'deposit)
       (t (error "Unknown request -- MAKE-ACCOUNT ~s" m))))))
  #'dispatch)

(defvar acc (make-account 1500))
(funcall (funcall acc 'withdraw) 50)
(funcall (funcall acc 'deposit) 75)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you help me to solve my Problem. Very kind of you !!!